# Drop the value that matches the string from list in python

Tags: python, pandas, string, list

I have a list that contains strings. I want to drop out the ones that have specific strings using python.

For example:

```
my_sample_list = ["I am practicing Python", "I am practicing Java", "I am practicing SQL"]
```

I want to drop out the element that contains `"SQL"` and I will be left with:

```
my_new_sample_list = ["I am practicing Python", "I am practicing Java"]
```

How can I do that in python, please? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use a list comprehension with a condition.

Comment: Don't think of it as "dropping".  Think of it as creating a new list without those items.  Does that make it clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the strings and check if the pattern is contained in it or not.

```
my_sample_list = ["I am practicing Python", "I am practicing Java", "I am practicing SQL"]

pattern = 'SQL'
my_new_sample_list = [s for s in my_sample_list if pattern not in s]
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn them to sets and do an intersection and back to list

```
list(set(my_sample_list).intersection(set(my_new_sample_list)))


['I am practicing Java', 'I am practicing Python']
```

Answer (score 1):

Two basic approaches:

1. Build a new array containing only valid entries:

```
new=[ entry if 'SQL' not in entry for entry in old ]
```

- Advantage: pretty foolproof
- Disadvantage: double the memory

2. Remove the element with the invalid entry

- Advantage: very low resource use
- Disadvantage: not trivial to write. Easy to create weird bugs